# Google webmasters adding crawl URL parameters

Tags: google-search-console, url

Google Webmasters has an option to add URL parameters: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters

My site uses URLs of this format:

- `http://example.com/tags/ocean/page1?perpage=20`
- `http://example.com/tags/flower/page5?perpage=30`

Adding `perpage` param is straightforward. But how do I add `page` as a parameter? Is it even possible?

Comment: In the context of your URLs, `page` is not a URL parameter, so you cannot use this tool to control access. What are you trying to do? It looks like pagination so the `rel="canonical"` should probably be set to `/page1`?

Comment: If you set rel=canonical to page1 then the other pages likely wont be indexed, whilst isnt the correct way of dealing with pagination.

Comment: @user29671 Sorry, yes, for general pagination you probably don't want to set a `rel=canonical`, however, these would seem to be _tag_ result pages with 20 - 30 items per page which you arguably don't want to be indexed (but still crawled and followed). With the OP trying to isolate this "parameter" in the Google tool also suggests that perhaps they don't want these pages indexed.

Comment: So would the solution be to change the URL format to: http://example.com/tags/ocean?perpage=20&page=1? Is this (traditional) format better than the current one? And yes, I want each and every page indexed by Google.